# attach Visibility Binding DataGrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight

How I can change the DataGrid column contents based on chosen from list as (Customer, Employee, etc.)  via visibility binding in c# silver-light?

**I am trying with this BUT it not work!! (I am newbie also I am not understood it good)**

```
<sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FooDataGridColumn"     Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding ID}" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BarDataGridColumn" Header="Bar" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
```

if you have any website, tutorial, please help me!